# Can't figure out what to put in soup.select. (Doing a variation on automating boring stuff with Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm doing the chapter'Downloading All XKCD Comics,' but with Nasa's daily photos. I have got to the point where I want the code to select a button, to go to the next page. On the page https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap191231.html the go back button is <. And I can't figure out how to select it.

````
#downloads nasa's daily photos.
import requests, os, bs4

#loads web page
url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap191231.html'
os.makedirs('nasa_daily_photos2019', exist_ok=True) #makes directory for photos

while not url.endswith('191225.html'):
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    image_elem = soup.select('img') #finds image
    if image_elem == []:
        print('Could not find image.')
    else:
        image_url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/' + image_elem[0].get('src')
        print('Downloading image %s...' % (image_url))
        res = requests.get(image_url)
        res.raise_for_status

    #save image to folder
        image_file = open(os.path.join('nasa_daily_photos2019', os.path.basename(image_url)), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            image_file.write(chunk)
        image_file.close()

    #now slects the '<' or previous page button
    prev_link = soup.select('a[<]')[0]
    url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/' + prev_link.get('href')```

I get the error: raise SelectorSyntaxError(msg, self.pattern, index)
soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Malformed attribute selector at position 1
  line 1:
a[<]
 ^
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS pseudo-class [`:contains()`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:contains) and if you want to select only one element, you can use `.select_one()` instead of `.select()`:

```
#now slects the '<' or previous page button
prev_link = soup.select_one('a:contains("<")')
url = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/' + prev_link.get('href')
```